# Get the Employee Details

Tags: python, pandas, spyder, xlrd

I have a excel sheet containing a lot of Employee Details data like (Employee name, Employee ID, Email id, First Name, Last name, Location, Group, Joining Date etc).

Is it possible in python if i execute code and let us say i enter employee id, it should give all details of that employee.

The reason why i ask is i have the excel sheet containing data of 180k employees. It's becoming difficult to fetch data if i need data of a particular employee.

Can someone guide me how can i do it?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. Please read the following documentation, then [edit] and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: I am sorry and will not repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the excel using `pandas.read_excel`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\\Users\\APatilX0106320\\Python\\User.xlsx')
df = df[df['Emp Num'].isin(['K890', 'K2'])]
print(df)
df.to_excel("Output1.xlsx",index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your code its working, one small request right now its giving data for one employee what if i need data for multiple employees

Comment: i have modified your code what if i need details of multiple employees (U891,Y678)